# VM won't boot after imaging with clonezilla

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, vmware-workstation, clonezilla

I am trying to create a VM for one of my systems with VMWare Workstation. I create the VM, make sure that the virtual disk size, memory size matches that of the laptop.

I boot the VM to a clonezilla ISO and restore the disk to an image I have of the laptop. After the restore is complete it reboots and goes right to PXE boot. I have edited the boot order in the BIOS to put the virtual hard drive first and network boot last.

Could this be a compatibility issue causing it not to boot? I am currently at a loss.

Comment: laptop hardware is very specialized and VM "hardware" is very generic. you will definitely have difficulties imaging a laptop and just booting it on VMWare. you are more likely to be successful with a P2V converter: https://www.altaro.com/vmware/vmware-converter-p2v/

Comment: very important to use EFI with modern Windows: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/612813/virt-manager-change-firmware-after-installation ..and heres for VMM/KVM: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1024835/how-to-create-dynamic-qcow2-image-from-windows-c-drive/1460193#1460193